# What is the difference between the approachs of annotation on nested class type parameter?

Tags: java, notnull

```
org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull

public static void func(Foo.Bar.@NotNull Baz arg0) {

}


public static void func(@NotNull Foo.Bar.Baz arg0) {

}


public static void func(@NotNull Foo.Bar.@NotNull Baz arg0) {

}
```

What is the difference between the approachs of annotation on nested class type parameter?

Which one is recommanded?

Comment: Does this even compile? To me this looks like a exam question (with some twist because only one looks compilable), is that the case?

Comment: @Thomas It does compile. `@NotNull` has the `ElementType` of `TYPE_USE`, so it is possible to use it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are only syntactically different. Semantically, they all mean "this parameter should not be null", and practically, all three compiles to the same null check on the parameter.

The reason why all three works is because `NotNull` has the `ElementType` of `TYPE_USE`, so you can annotate any "type use" with `NotNull`. Well, the `Bar` in `Foo.Bar` is a use of the type `Bar`, so you can annotate that by doing `Foo.@NotNull Bar`.

This raises the question of why does `NotNull` have `ElementType.TYPE_USE` in the first place. It certainly is not to allow you to have 3 ways of saying the exact same thing. A more likely reason is to allow you to do this:

```
List<@NotNull String> listWithNotNullElements;
```

Anyway, all three of these compile to the same byte code, as in all 3 cases, `NotNull` is annotating the *parameter*.

All three of the following:

```
package io.github.sweeper777;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    public void f( Foo.@NotNull Bar x) {
    }
}
class Foo {
    static class Bar {
    }
}
```

```
package io.github.sweeper777;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    public void f(@NotNull Foo.@NotNull Bar x) {
    }
}
class Foo {
    static class Bar {
    }
}
```

```
package io.github.sweeper777;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    public void f(@NotNull Foo.Bar x) {
    }
}
class Foo {
    static class Bar {
    }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
Compiled from "Main.java"
public class io.github.sweeper777.Main {
  public io.github.sweeper777.Main();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: return

  public void f(io.github.sweeper777.Foo$Bar);
    Code:
       0: aload_1
       1: ifnonnull     8
       4: iconst_0
       5: invokestatic  #36                 // Method $$$reportNull$$$0:(I)V
       8: return

  private static void $$$reportNull$$$0(int);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #38                 // String Argument for @NotNull parameter \'%s\' of %s.%s must not be null
       2: iconst_3
       3: anewarray     #2                  // class java/lang/Object
       6: dup
       7: iconst_0
       8: ldc           #39                 // String x
      10: aastore
      11: dup
      12: iconst_1
      13: ldc           #40                 // String io/github/sweeper777/Main
      15: aastore
      16: dup
      17: iconst_2
      18: ldc           #41                 // String f
      20: aastore
      21: invokestatic  #47                 // Method java/lang/String.format:(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
      24: new           #49                 // class java/lang/IllegalArgumentException
      27: dup_x1
      28: swap
      29: invokespecial #52                 // Method java/lang/IllegalArgumentException."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      32: athrow
}
```